# Referencing ExPex example from a different subfile?

Tags: cross-referencing, subfiles, expex

Is there any way I can get subfiles to correctly reference ExPex example numbers? Say I had a main file which contained two subfiles. One subfile contains an ExPex example, and the other contains a reference to that example (using the `\getref` command). The result this produces in the main file is this:

[image: Main file:]

This is correct, and I have no problems with this output. However, when I compile fileB.tex as a subfile (the file which references the ExPex example from fileA.tex), I get this:

[image: fileB:]

What I want is for fileB to read:

> This is a reference to (1).

Is there any way of resolving this? Or is it a problem with `subfiles` / `expex`? I've tried using the package `xr` so that the subfiles point to each other, but this hasn't worked. I need this for a thesis where I will be compiling individual chapters that will point to examples from other chapters in some cases. I've had no problem with the `\ref` command across subfiles when referencing sections, tables, etc. but still would like a way to cross-reference ExPex examples. Any help would be immensely appreciated, thanks!

MWE with code for main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\subfile{fileA}
\subfile{fileB}

\end{document}
```

fileA.tex:

```
\documentclass[./main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\section{Original}

\ex<ex1> This is a test.
\xe

\end{document}
```

and fileB.tex:

```
\documentclass[./main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\section{Reference}

This is a reference to (\getref{ex1}).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. ExPex doesn't use LaTeX counters, but I think you *can* use regular `\label` and `\ref` with ExPex examples instead of using the ExPex methods.  Would this be a practical solution? If not it may be some work to get the ExPex count registers to work in the way you want.

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but you may want to have a look at [`expex-acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/expex-acro)

Comment: @Niranjan `expex-acro` doesn't really provide anything specific to this problem.

Comment: @AlanMunn It I guess has a referencing method which does use LaTeX labels

Comment: @Niranjan Yes, but using LaTeX labels with ExPex doesn't depend on using it.

Comment: @AlanMunn this mostly works, thank you. However, in the thesis examples will be numbered by chapter (chp.exnum), e.g., 1.1, 1.7, etc. The `\label` and `\ref` method doesn't produce the full example numbers from my testing. The hyperlinks also take me to the section heading rather than the example.

Comment: @AlanMunn Sorry, my bad.

Comment: I also suppose the individual chapters will only be for drafts, so this isn't a huge problem. The final full document will work anyway so there will be no problems for the reader – it would be more for my supervisor's benefit in being able to refer to my other chapters to see which examples I'm talking about. Thank you both for your suggestions!

Comment: Just in case you are not aware, macro `\includeonly` (use only in preamble) causes latex to produce document based on files included in its argument. The requirement is you split your thesis into say chapters and use a set of `\include{<file>}`s in the main document. All references will be intact. I find `subfiles` convenient but only within chapters if let's say I want to avoid compiling the whole chapter to test individual complex tables or graph.

Comment: @geordiekidd Use `\gathertags` from the `expex` package, followed by `\input{main-tags}` (in the preamble of `main.tex`). See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following lines to the preamble of your main file:

```
\gathertags
\input{XXX-tags}% XXX is the name of the main file (without .tex)
```

Run LaTeX at least once on your main file to collect the labels, before LaTeXing the subfiles. Likewise, whenever some labels change in another subfile, you have to run LaTeX again on the main file in order to write the new information to `XXX-tags.tex`.

In your example, the file `main.tex` would look like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\gathertags      % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\input{main-tags}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}

\subfile{fileA}
\subfile{fileB}

\end{document}
```

After running `pdflatex main` you can do `pdflatex fileB`, and will obtain the reference to `(1)`.

Comment: +1 Totally forgot about `\gathertags`.

Comment: Wow this is really elegant and simple, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, `\inlcude` should perfectly do for this case. If you split document by chapters, with a macro `\chapter`, you can avoid all this hassle with references if you append `\includeonly` in preamble. Just beware `\include` generates an extra page break, similarly to `\chapter`, so you shouldn't use it with documents split into sections, subsections etc. This would be the only inconvenience.

Consider the code below for a self-contained file that generates additional three files to include:`chapeter1.tex`, `chapter2.tex` and `chapter3.tex`. The document is split into chapters, which are included in the main file via `\include`. For instance if I wanted to produce only chapter 2, I'd just append `\includeonly{chapter2}` in my preamble. All reference would still work

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{chapter1.tex}
\chapter{First}
\kant[1][1]

\begin{table}[tbh]
  \caption{Data in chapter 1}\label{tab:ch1}
\end{table}

References: \cref{fig:ch2,fig:ch3,tab:ch3}.
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{chapter2.tex}
\chapter{Second}
\kant[1][2]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \caption{Graph in chapter 2}\label{fig:ch2}
\end{figure}

References: \cref{tab:ch1,fig:ch3,tab:ch3}.
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{chapter3.tex}
\chapter{Third}
\kant[1][3]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \caption{Graph in chapter 3}\label{fig:ch3}
\end{figure}

\kant[1][4]

\begin{table}[tbh]
  \caption{Data in chapter 1}\label{tab:ch3}
\end{table}

Refereces: \cref{tab:ch1}, \cref{fig:ch2}.
\end{filecontents*}
%%%
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\includeonly{chapter2}


\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I hadn’t really considered this workflow but it looks like a really neat solution. In this case, though, wouldn’t each chapter compiled via the `\includeonly` command still have the thesis title page, toc, etc.? Or does that command simply compile the file named in the argument with the preamble of the main file, and nothing else?

Comment: It does compile everything else meaning the title, table of content, list of figures, list of tables, bibliography etc. `\includeonly` affects arguments of `\include`. For instance, if your Appendix was in the main document (not included by `\include`), it would also be compiled.